# How do I copy values only and paste into a new google sheet using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using the below I am trying to copy all the values from a single tab, create a new sheet and rename it based on various cells within the sheet and paste by value into the new sheet as its for reference to others only. I've removed the actual URL.

```
function exportTab() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(" ");
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getYear();
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(ss.getSheetByName("Overview").getRange("B4").getValue() + " " + today.getFullYear() + " - Square Programming");
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
}
```

This script does 99% of what I want it to except it copies everything across and pastes in the formulas leaving my new sheet full of #REF errors

I have tried amending the last row of script with alternative commands but nothing else seems to work correctly.

I'm assuming I need to amend or expand on this  " SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet); " to achieve what I need, though the answer alludes me.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the official docs on `copyTo`? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could fix the #REF errors by using `getDisplayValue()` instead of `getValue()`

Your code would look like this:

```
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(ss.getSheetByName("Overview").getRange("B4").getDisplayValue() + " " + today.getFullYear() + " - Square Programming");
```

If you want to disregard functions entirely, your best course of action would be to use a Regex to check the value of your values before exporting them to the new spreadsheet.